# Do rdflib and gevent work nicely together?

Tags: gevent, web-frameworks, rdflib, greenlets

Does rdflib's (e.g., SPARQL/SPARQL Update) work well with gevent in an asynchronous web framework setting (gunicorn/pyramid, Flask, ...)? One of the goals is to offload longer-running (but not that long to require external message queues) into their own greenlet workers.

Can't find any definite pointers either way. And checking it out is not reliable option, as figuring out subtle effects require advanced testing setting.

**UPDATE**: I've found a Flask [application for provenance visualization](https://github.com/Data2Semantics/provoviz), which is doing socket.io, and uses gevent/gunicorn and rdflib. So, I guess, the combination is compatible. Not sure if there are caveats.